# Reduce computation time by using vectorization in MATLAB instead of multiple for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I have a long MATLAB code which takes a lot of time due to numerous `for` loops. I try to eliminate them but it looks like I do not understand the vectorization concept. To be more specific, consider the following simple example with two vectors with different sizes:

```
a1=[1 2];
a2=[1 2 3];
```

I want to compute`a1/a2` in a "piece-wise" sense. For that, I use the following `for` loops

```
div=0;
for i=1:size(a1,2)
 for j=1:size(a2,2)
  div=div+a1(i)/a2(j);
 end
end
```

How can I vectorize such two for loops? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two good options: `bsxfun` and `ndgrid`. Given two row vectors:

```
a1=[1 2];
a2=[1 2 3];
```

**bsxfun**

The old-school way is with two `repmat` calls. Virtual replication can now be done with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
divM = bsxfun(@rdivide,a1,a2');
div = sum(divM(:))
```

Faster and more memory-efficient than `repmat`.

**ndgrid**

When you think "all combinations", think [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html).

```
[ii,jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(a2),1:numel(a1))
divM = a1(jj)./a2(ii);
div = sum(divM(:))
```

Comment: @LuisMendo You're right! Ah, curse you! Why didn't i think to just invert `a2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just **matrix multiplication**: a column vector times a row vector gives a matrix with all combinations of element-wise products:

```
divs = a1(:) * (1./a2(:)).';
div = sum(divs(:));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you.

```
a1=[1 2];
a2=[1 2 3];
div_matrix = a1' ./ repmat(a2, [size(a1,2), 1])
sum(div_matrix(:))
```